# Why does this code take such a long time?

Tags: python

I was trying a practice problem in codility. The following is the code. I do not understand why it takes such a long time to run. Here, the input A is a list of six elements yet, it takes more than five seconds to run. Could anyone tell me the reason for this?

```
def solution(A):
    ln=len(A)
    if ln>1:
        mid = ln//2
        left_h=A[:mid]
        right_h=A[mid:]
        a=solution(left_h)
        b=solution(right_h)
        i=0
        j=0

        tmp=0

        while i<mid and j<ln-mid:
            if left_h[i]>right_h[j]:
                tmp+=1
                i+=1
                j+=1
        return a+b+tmp
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: I've waited more than a minute and it has not completed

Comment: Debugging by single-stepping or adding print statements will let you find where the code is getting stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while i<mid and j<ln-mid:
    if left_h[i]>right_h[j]:
        tmp+=1
        i+=1
        j+=1
```

If the `if` statement is false no variables are updated, and you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

It enters an infinite loop if `left_h[i]>right_h[j]` is false.

You probably mean

```
    while i<mid and j<ln-mid:
        if left_h[i]>right_h[j]:
            tmp+=1
        i+=1
        j+=1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
left_h=A[:mid]
right_h=A[mid:]
```

That bit *copies* a chunk of the list you pass in each time the function recurses. Working with offsets and not copying the list should improve performance dramatically.